# Powershell - Encoding to export AD thumbnailPhoto

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, active-directory, arrays

I use a powershell script to export the active directory thumbnailPhoto attribute to a sql server table.
The goal is to display the photo using asp.net.

The problem I have is that I convert it to a string (column in tsql is nvarchar) which then gives me RGB values. Not using string just gives me "System.Byte[]"

The values are stored like this:

```
255 216 255 225 0 24 69 120 105 102...
```

instead of what I was hoping:

```
ffd8ffe1001845786966000049492a...
```

This is a part of my script:

```
ForEach ($user in $users) {
$tempUser = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ sAMAccountName=""; thumbnail="" }
$tempUser.thumbnail = $user.thumbnailPhoto
}
....
$datatable = New-Object System.Data.Datatable "insert"
$datatable.Columns.Add("thumbnail") | Out-Null
ForEach ($user in $SQLusers) {
    $row = $datatable.NewRow()
$row["thumbnail"] = [String]$user.thumbnail
$datatable.Rows.Add($row)
}
```

So my question drifts into two directions:

- how can I display above RGB values with asp.net?
- or how can I transform the RGB values to get the correct byte encoding?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
[Convert]::ToBase64String($user.thumbnailPhoto)
```